# constantly checking if new email has arrived using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I want to monitor my yahoo mail and check if new email arrives in my inbox. To do that I must refresh the page(say every 60 seconds) and check if there is a new email. I couldn't come up with anything better than this :

```
try:
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 604800).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#mail-app-component > div > div > div.D_F.ab_FT.em_N.ek_BB.iz_A.H_6D6F > div > div > div.W_6D6F.H_6D6F.cZ1RN91d_n.o_h.p_R.em_N.D_F > div > div.p_R.Z_0.iy_h.iz_A.W_6D6F.H_6D6F.k_w.em_N.c22hqzz_GN > ul > li:nth-child({4}) > a')))
    while True:
        driver.refresh()
except:
    print('no')
    driver.quit()
```

I put search variable in try which detects if there's a new email in my inbox(the css web elements are the same on yahoo. They differ by just one number, which indicates the (n-1)-th email that I received) and I want the page to refresh every 60 seconds and check again for new email. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

turns out it's not that difficult.

```
while True:
    n = 4
    try:
        search = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'#mail-app-component > div > div > div.D_F.ab_FT.em_N.ek_BB.iz_A.H_6D6F > div > div > div.W_6D6F.H_6D6F.cZ1RN91d_n.o_h.p_R.em_N.D_F > div > div.p_R.Z_0.iy_h.iz_A.W_6D6F.H_6D6F.k_w.em_N.c22hqzz_GN > ul > li:nth-child({n}) > a')))
        
        n+=1
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```